# show and hide divs with multiple class names jquery checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have many dives with multiple classes as

```
<div class="my-gallery">
  <div class="LargeFace Neutral Happy"></div>
  <div class="Sad Neutral Happy"></div>
  <div class="LargeFace Surprise Happy"></div>
  <div class="LargeFace Fear Happy"></div>
</div>
```

And I have multiple check boxes which have all those values. e.g LargeFace or Happy and else.

```
<label class="with-label">
  <input id="c_b" type="checkbox" name="r1" value="Neutral" />Neutral
</label>
<label class="with-label">
  <input id="c_b" type="checkbox" name="r1" value="LargeFace">Large Face
</label>
```

Through this code I am getting all those checkbox values to an array

```
 $('.with-label').on "click", ->
    allVals = []
    $('.with-label :checked').each ->
    allVals.push $(this).val()
    return
    console.log allVals
 return
```

Right now I am really really struggling for filtering my divs on the basis of this array values. for example. User have selected multiple check boxes and create an array as `["Happy", "Fear"]`

I want to make something which will filter `#my-gallery` on the basis on that array. If there are 2 those values in an array then All those divs, which contain that classes should appear and other should disappear, So for other values? Is that possible? please help I am struggling with this for so long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing the values in array, You can create a class selector for the value and then push it in array.

```
 $('.with-label :checked').each ->
  allVals.push("." + $(this).val())
  return
```

which will create the array as:

```
[".LargeFace",".Happy"]
```

Then use `.join()` to create the class selectors, traverse to parent and show them  :

```
 $('.my-gallery > div').hide(); //hide all first
 $(allVals.join(',')).show(); //show based on array values
```

Comment: didnt you notice i was showing something within the #my-gallery?

Comment: Okay but its working on `uncheck` options.. it should show and hide as I asked :) its just showing and the also not remove the class from allVal?

Comment: @ijunaidfarooq: for that you have to redeclare array element on each check/encheck event.

Comment: But if on every check I will re-declare it will conatin the values of checked ones?

Comment: can you create a problem fiddle? would be easy to resolve then.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-gallery > div').each(() => {
    if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').some(className => allVals.includes(className))) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Place this directly after you create your `allVals` array.
It goes through all your gallery divs and checks if at least one of the classes belongs to `allVals`.

Older javascript syntax:

```
$('.my-gallery > div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').some(function(className) {
        return allVals.indexOf(className) !== -1;
    })) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course, this is ES6 javascript, I will give you an edit with old javascript code as well, if you need to support old browsers.

Comment: or simply try with my update, I had missed a closing )

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In previous function of jquery use your element which need to be tackle

```
$('.with-label').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.with-label').prev(your_element).toggle();
});
```